# Issue deploying ASP.net angular application to IIS

Tags: c#, angularjs, node.js, angular, iis

I am trying to deploy my application to IIS and everything seems to work however when I go to open up the web site I get the error below in the browser. I tried running it locally on the server its self with dotnet "myapp.dll" and It loads everything accept my client side stuff as seen below it fails on a node process. (So my guess is it has something to do with node not serving my client side?)
Any help resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

## Error in browser

[image]

## Error in cmd line when I run dotnet locally on the server its self

[image]

## Other info

```
 I have the "AspNetCoreModule" installed and enabled in IIS
 Both dev machine and server are running the same versions of the following:
   dotnet
   node
```

Comment: are you trying to deploy the node server on IIS or angular application only along with your asp .net application?

Comment: Deploy my anuglar application with my asp.net on IIS. @VaibhavKumarGoyal

Comment: so again to clarify over this i believe the angular application is a separate application all together within itself , can you share your IIS hosting application and URL rewrite rules ? @Snowman08

Comment: I figured it out - see my answer below @VaibhavKumarGoyal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out I installed "dotnet-hosting-2.1.3-win.exe" and never restarted IIS "iisreset /noforce" and presto it worked...... 5 days uninstalling, reinstalling, and all it took was a simple command to fix it.